# Angular 4 Library @Input

Tags: angular, npm, yo, angular-library

Hi guys I need a bit of help, as I can't seem to get it to work. I think I might be using the incorrect syntax or something.

I am currently building Angular 4 libraries using YO https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library

So everything is working except for the `@Input` decorators.

Some simple code here

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-component',
  template: `<h1>Sample component {{hello}}</h1>`
})
export class SampleComponent {
  @Input('hello') hello: string;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I build the package using npm and then import to dist into another application and then import the module.

I then use this component as follows:

```
<sample-component hello="koos"></sample-component>
```

It works very well and the correct message is displayed.

My question is regarding when I bind the hello property like this

```
<sample-component [hello]="koos"></sample-component>
```

and I have the variable `koos = 'hello I am koos;'` in the back-end it does not bind to it at all?

Should I be using other ways to do this? Is there another way to bind @Input and @Output variables?

Your insight would be appreciated.

As requested the parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  koos: 'Ek is Koos';
}
```

I obviously removed the other code, as this is the only required section.

Comment: What's the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: @JamieRees no error message at all, it's just not binding to it. If it's plain text and I am not using the [ ] brackets it works, but as soon as I want to bind it using the [ ] brackets it does not display the value at all.

Comment: Can you show the parent component where you are declaring and assigning the variable `koos`

Comment: @JamieRees I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

```
koos: 'Ek is Koos'; // < --- you create type 'Ek is Koos'
```

The solution is to create like this:

```
koos:string = 'Ek is Koos';
```

Comment: Nope tried it that way around as well. Does not work. I added the decorator name explicitly to make sure that it is not that, that is causing the issue.

Comment: I corrected my answer when you correct your question

Comment: sorry first time was really my mistake )

Comment: I will retest now. Can't believe I made that mistake. Will mark as answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It was that. Such a rookie mistake.